# Firebase Database showing duplicates in App?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, duplicates

[image]

[image]

I am trying to see all those Contacts which I have on my phone and have registered on the app. I am able to see the registered contact, but as you can see, I have a single entry in the database by username John and in the Android app, it is showing more than one. I only want to show it once. I don't know the reason, Can anybody Help? **Here is the Code**

```
public class UsersFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mUserlist;
ArrayList<ProfileInfo> list, userList;
DatabaseReference db;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_users, container, false);

    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserInfo");

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.UserRecyclerView);
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    list = new ArrayList<>();
    userList = new ArrayList<>();
    mUserlist = new UsersAdapter(userList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mUserlist);
    displayContactList();
    return view;
}


private void displayContactList() {
    Cursor numberList = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query
            (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, null, null, null);
    assert numberList != null;
    while (numberList.moveToNext()) {
        String name = numberList.getString(numberList.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String phoneNumber = numberList.getString(numberList.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        ProfileInfo info = new ProfileInfo(name, phoneNumber);
        list.add(info);
        showAppUsers(info);
    }
}

private void showAppUsers(ProfileInfo info){
    Query query = db.orderByChild("phoneNumber").equalTo(info.getPhoneNumber());
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists() ){
                String phone ="",
                       name="";
                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    if (child.child("phoneNumber").getValue() != null)
                        name = Objects.requireNonNull(child.child("userName").getValue()).toString();
                    if (child.child("userName").getValue() != null)
                        phone = Objects.requireNonNull(child.child("phoneNumber").getValue()).toString();

                    ProfileInfo info = new ProfileInfo(name, phone);
                    userList.add(info);
                    mUserlist.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    return;

                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see in your database, you only have a single record. When using the following query:

```
Query query = db.orderByChild("phoneNumber").equalTo(info.getPhoneNumber());
```

Indeed a single record will be returned. The problem is not your query. The problem lies in the fact that you are calling `showAppUsers()` method from within a while loop. Most probably, your `numberList` contains three records, hence that behavior. So at every iteration you add to the `userList` the value of the `userName` property. To solve this, get the call to `showAppUsers()` method out of the loop so you can get only one result.

Comment: I tried it, But after calling it from outside of while loop it doesn't show any users.

Comment: It doesn't because `info.getPhoneNumber()` return nothing. Be sure to pass a value to the equalTo method. Try with a hardcoded value, does it work?